# executing shell command with | (pipe) using NSTask

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to execute this comamnd `ps -ef | grep test` using NSTask but I can't get the | grep test to be included in the NSTask:

This is what I'm using currently to get the output of ps -ef into a string then I need to somehow get the pid of the process test

```
NSTask *task;
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/ps"];

NSArray *arguments;
arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-ef", nil];
[task setArguments: arguments];    
NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];

NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

[task launch];

NSData *data;
data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

NSString *string;
string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data
                               encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog (@"got\n%@", string);
```

Comment: Why don’t you do the filtering in your program instead? Piping to grep will be slower.

Answer (score 22):

Piping is a feature provided by shells, such as `/bin/sh`. You may try launching your command via such a shell:

```
/* ... */
[task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/sh"];
/* ... */
arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-c", @"ps -ef | grep test", nil];
```

However, if you let the user supply a value (instead of hard-coding e.g. `test`), you are making the program susceptible to shell injection attacks, which are kind of like SQL injection. An alternative, which doesn't suffer from this problem, is to use a pipe object to connect the standard output of `ps` with the standard input of `grep`:

```
NSTask *psTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
NSTask *grepTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];

[psTask setLaunchPath: @"/bin/ps"];
[grepTask setLaunchPath: @"/bin/grep"];

[psTask setArguments: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-ef", nil]];
[grepTask setArguments: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"test", nil]];

/* ps ==> grep */
NSPipe *pipeBetween = [NSPipe pipe];
[psTask setStandardOutput: pipeBetween];
[grepTask setStandardInput: pipeBetween];

/* grep ==> me */
NSPipe *pipeToMe = [NSPipe pipe];
[grepTask setStandardOutput: pipeToMe];

NSFileHandle *grepOutput = [pipeToMe fileHandleForReading];

[psTask launch];
[grepTask launch];

NSData *data = [grepOutput readDataToEndOfFile];

/* etc. */
```

This uses built-in Foundation functionality to perform the same steps as the shell does when it encounters the `|` character.

Finally as others have pointed out, the usage of `grep` is overkill. Just add this to your code:

```
NSArray *lines = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSArray *filteredLines = [lines filteredArrayUsingPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF contains[c] 'test'"]];
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning that "Piping is a feature provided by shells,...". I was looking for the reason for years!

Comment: Capturing the output into a string is OK if there's a small amount of output, but if the data output by the task is larger than the buffer, the process may deadlock. In those cases, piping to grep is better. That's how I arrived here! Piping to grep solved my problem, I was searching for a single instance of a substring. (See https://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2003/Jan/msg01106.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to call [task waitUntilExit] before you launch the task, so that the process can finish running before you read the output.

Comment: process does get finished and I get the output of ps -ef in a String. But i also need to do grep test on that output.